# Python : OK style to combine regex and group into single line?

Tags: python, regex

Many python tutorials show a two line example of using `re`.

```
match=re.search('aa?yushi','ayushi')
match.group()
```

Is it recommended style to combine the two?

```
re.search('aa?yushi','ayushi').group()
```

I tried but it failed.

```
re.match('\d','a1b2c3d').group()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
```

What's the trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's legal, but it's discouraged because there is no guarantee that the regex actually matches; when it doesn't match it returns `None`, and `None` has no `.group` method, so you get a less than helpful error message, as you've seen.

In your case, you accidentally triggered this by using `re.match` instead of `re.search`; `re.match` is implicitly anchored at the beginning of the string, so:

```
re.match('\d','a1b2c3d').group()
```

fails because the string being tested doesn't begin with a digit. By contest, it would work fine with `re.search`, which has no implicit anchoring:

```
re.search(r'\d','a1b2c3d').group()
```

Note: I used a raw string for the regex pattern, because you should *always* use raw strings for regexes; it works without it in this case, but only by accident, and only in Python (because Python makes the decision to treat unrecognized escapes as being literal backslashes; if your pattern had used `\a`, `\b` or many other escapes that have meaning both in `str` literals and regex, it wouldn't have worked).

Comment: I was following the explanation of match vs search as given in this page : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-re-search-vs-re-match/ Their explanation is search is for multi-line string and match for first line or single line string. There is no mention of anchoring there. Though testing on the cmd line proves your statement. Is there a good tutorial pointer for the different incarnations of `re` pattern finding?

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can in python 3.7

[image]